# force:data:tree:export / force:data:tree:import across __r relationships

Tags: salesforcedx, data-export, scratch-org, data-import, cli

I am still fairly new to SaleforceDX.  I have been tasked with putting together a sample data plan matching a small portion of our production data, for our new Scratch-Orgs.  With foreign-key type relationships, I am having no problems whatsoever (Using the '@' symbol to build references like @AccountRef1).  However, I am failing to see how this would be done when there isn't such a foreign-key type of field (master-detail and __r relationships specifically.)  I have read a bit about putting together embedded queries, but that seems like it could get ugly, and I don't completely understand it.  My question is: how do I import related objects without a field to put the @ related object reference into?

For example: A relates to B.  How do I specify a relationship like B.ClassOfA.Id='@RefId' in my Plan's JSON file for B.

Comment: You shouldn't do this manually - you use the `force:data:tree:export` command with the `-p` flag to generate the plan file with your json data files. Can you specify the relationship query you're using to extract the data?

Comment: @ThomasTaylor I'm not using a relationship query.  I am just independently querying A and B, and then trying to tie-in the relationship after the fact.  I have tried using the -p command, but all I get back is the same records as doing it without the -p, plus a series of errors like 'ERROR:  Reference Group not found for OwnerId.  Skipping record a0p0W000009fZZFQA2.'

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Please provide an example of how to query across relationships (if you can), so I can upvote you and make your answer the accepted one.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible yet, but may be in the future.  The following YouTube video explains the plans for a Shape Pilot currently in the making:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDBb0RDqY2A